# cloth simulation penetrates thorugh the collider

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am recently trying to make pants, therefore I set my human mesh as

collider, but the pants still go through the legs.

how can I fix it?

Comment: need more details, what are your collision settings on the pants and body?

Comment: just default settings.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up the pants as `Cloth`, acticating its `ClothCollision` and setting the legs as `Collision`, it should work immediately. Note that the pants can still penetrate at some spots if

- resolution of your pants is too low
- forces (e.g. sewing) are too high
- cloth collision distance is set too low
- they intersect at the beginning of the calculation already

Answer (score 0):

As Dimali mentioned, make sure collision is checked.

Collision distance settings can solve the intersection, but at the cost of leaving large gaps between the cloth and the collision mesh. A better solution is to increase the step count of the simulation (Quality) until satisfactory results are obtained. This will increase simulation time, so you many still need to fiddle with other settings if it is taking too long.